# Input mp3 file returns 0

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, blob, mp3

When I try to input an `mp3` file the `$_FILES` returns `null`.

Controller:

```
$audio = $_FILES['muziek']['tmp_name'];

if ($audio != ''){
     $audioContent = file_get_contents($audio);
     $this->load->model('muziek_model');
     $this->muziek_model->insertMuziek($audioContent);
}
var_dump($audio);
var_dump($audioContent);
```

View:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('Muziek/uploadMuziek');?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo form_label('MP3 Bestand:', 'muziek'); ?></td>
        <td><input type="file" name="muziek" id="muziek" accept=".mp3" style="margin-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 35px; color: black" class="btn btn-login form-control login-formcontrol bg-white"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <?php echo form_submit('knop', 'Uploaden', 'class = "btn btn-login login-formcontrol"'); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

When I select an mp3 file audio should not be null

Comment: i see no reference to `$_FILES` here

Comment: it shows it now i formatted it wrong sorry

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: `print_r($_FILES['muziek'])` what is the exact response?

Comment: the vardump returns null for audio and for audiocontent is sais its not defined

Comment: please re-read my previous comment. it is different from what you assumed.

Comment: Array ( [name] => Pigeon John - The Bomb [Official Video].mp3 [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 )

Comment: Well there you go: `[error] => 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File uploads can fail for a variety of reasons. https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Your's is failing because it is too big:

> Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive
>   in php.ini.

If you have access to `php.ini` you can change this variable to make it accept larger files.

Even if you do this with success, I would suggest checking for upload errors `if(!isset($_FILES['muziek']['tmp_name']) || $_FILES['muziek']['error'] !== 0) { echo 'error'; }` before trying to perform actions on a file that may or may not exist.

I personally use: https://github.com/verot/class.upload.php

but Codeigniter has an in-built upload library.

Comment: I cant get that working either i tried that do you know the location of the php.ini file by chance

Comment: Is this local or remote? Xampp or another ?

Comment: local i found it im trying to find the setting is there a way to make it unlimited?

Comment: on xampp it is in c:\xampp\php\php.ini. you can set it to like 200M or whatever. i think there is a limitation. you might also have to change `post_max_size`... just note: on hosting environments you'll be lucky if your provider lets you upload more than 10M. so you might have to institute something called "chunking" (dropzone has it, among others).

Comment: i host it myself i had some old pcs from work and i put a linux server on there